# replace a specific text in all files with a text from its own file name in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sed

Good Day!

I have files in Ubuntu like:

- ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K051.XLS
- ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K052.XLS
- ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K053.XLS

which are copy of a file "ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K036", the code of file is K036

File contents are the same

```
LOADED_AGRS   ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K036
AGG_DEFINE    200ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K036  $WERKS  K036                                          
AGG_1521      200ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K036
```

Here I have to replace the **code** wiith its own **code** according to filename.

for example:

file: ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K051.XLS

its code is K051, and I have to replace K036 to K051, so that content of the file would be:

```
LOADED_AGRS   ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K051
AGG_DEFINE    200ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K051  $WERKS  K051                                          
AGG_1521      200ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K051
```

Can anyone help out, please?

Comment: Since the files content is the SAME, it might be an easier approach for you to regenerate the files using a loop, where the loop index can be used in the filename as well as in the file, like "036" for your "K036" in your example

Comment: What do you mean with "File contents"?  Microsoft Excel uses the .xls extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the files contain K036 the below script will help you.

```
#!/bin/bash
directory="/path/to/file"

cd "$directory"

for file in ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K*.xls; do

    code=$(echo "$file" | cut -d'_' -f4 | cut -d'.' -f1)

    sed -i "s/K036/$code/g" "$file"


    echo "Code replaced in $file"
done
```

where the

> echo "$file" | cut -d'_' -f4 | cut -d'.' -f1

will extract the file name k051 from the filename

> sed -i "s/K036/$code/g" "$file"

will replace the old value with new one

So this would help you in your case.

Answer (score 2):

As Ron mentioned in the comment, you can do something like this with bash to generate the files with modified content that matches the index:

```bash
# Iterate over the values from 036 to 051
for i in {036..051}; do
  echo "Generating 'ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K${i}.XLS'"
  cat > ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K${i}.XLS << EOL
LOADED_AGRS   ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K${i}
AGG_DEFINE    200ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K${i} $WERKS  K${i}
AGG_1521      200ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K${i}
EOL
done
```

The above will generate the files as described in the current directory. The `cat > ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K${i}.XLS << EOL` uses a [heredoc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to generate the file. The filename and contents use the `$i` variable for the names. As the for loop executes, `i` gets incremented, i.e. `036`, `037`, `038`,...`051` etc. which is used to generate the file name and the contents accordingly.

If you want to use something like [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) to replace contents. Running the following in the directory where the files are should do the trick:

```bash
# Iterate over the files and replace contents
for f in ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K0{36..51}.XLS; do

  # Set a variable the same as the filename but strip off ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K
  n=${f//ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K/}

  # Further strip off the file extension
  n=${n%*.XLS}

  echo "Replacing K036 in $f with ${n}"

  # Replace the contents with the number found in the file name
  sed -i "s|K036|${n}|g" "$f"
done
```

Basically, we iterate over each file, set a variable name that contains the number from the filename by stripping the `ZAF_MM_CYCLE_K` and the `.XLS` using bash parameter expansion. Once the number is deduced, use sed to replace the contents on the given file. `sed -i` does an in-place replacement on the original file.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & parallel):

```
parallel sed -i \''s/K036/{=s/.*_(.*)\.XLS$/\1/=}/g'\' {} ::: *.XLS
```

Build and execute a separate sed script for each file ending in `.XLS` in the current directory.

The sed script will replace `K036` by the code following the last `_` in the filename and end before the final `.`.